# количество знаков после точки swift (Float)

Tags: ios, swift

есть число 0.5 как отобразить его как 0.500000
swift вообще позволяет такое делать? 
когда привожу число к Float все равно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[См. тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047374/string-formatting-of-a-double).

```
print(NSString(format: "%.6f", 0.5)) // 0.500000
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а без import UIKit никак больше нельзя?

Comment: Форматирование в любом случае предполагает перевести в строку подобным образом.

Comment: я понял тут просто на https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus
там в задание написано что нужно в аутпут 0.500000
импорт там не могу сделать

Comment: боже я так затупил сорри все ок оно требует нули
спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если представить цифру как строку, то можно вывести ее так

```
func roundToPlaces(places:Float){
    let aStr = String(format: "%05.6f", places)
    print(aStr)
} 
print(roundToPlaces(0.5))
```